# What's the difference between 'not in' and 'not exists'?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

What's the difference between `not in` and `not exists` in an Oracle query?

When do I use `not in`? And `not exist`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it serves the same purpose.

`not in` can **also** take literal values whereas `not exists` need a query to compare the results with.

EDIT: `not exists` could be good to use because it can `join` with the outer query & can lead to usage of index, if the criteria uses column that is indexed.

EDIT2: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists) question as well.

EDIT3: Let me take the above things back.
See [this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:442029737684) link. I think, it all depends on how the DB translates this & on database/indexes etc.

Comment: Don't forget about treatment of nulls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699424/what-the-difference-between-not-in-and-not-exists-in-oracle-query/1703712#1703712

Comment: The Tom Kyte link definitely gets to the root of the matter.

Answer (score 36):

The difference between **NOT IN** and **NOT EXISTS** becomes clear where there are `NULL` values included in the result.

For example:

```
create table test_a (col1 varchar2(30 char));
create table test_b (col1 varchar2(30 char));

insert into test_a (col1) values ('a');
insert into test_a (col1) values ('b');
insert into test_a (col1) values ('c');
insert into test_a (col1) values ('d');
insert into test_a (col1) values ('e');

insert into test_b (col1) values ('a');
insert into test_b (col1) values ('b');
insert into test_b (col1) values ('c');
insert into test_b (col1) values (null);
```

**Note**: They key difference is that `test_b` contains a `null` value.

```
select * from test_a where col1 not in (select col1 from test_b);
```

No rows returned

```
select * from test_a where 
    not exists
        (select 1 from test_b where test_b.col1 = test_a.col1);
```

Returns

```
col1
====
d
e
```

Comment: @Gold: I think you should accept this answer, will help future visitors to directly get the bull's eye.

Comment: But is is being stated here, that any string matches null in SQL? This is a little confusing.

Comment: This is so wierd - I ran into this problem today. I swear they updated the function.
I've used (and prefer) the 'not in' method countless times. Logically they should give the same answer.

Comment: ok - so one of my elves figured this out.. its because you have nulls in table test_b.

if you comment out the insert statement that creates the null, then you'll see the 'not in' works.

Answer (score 2):

There can be performance differences, with exists being faster.

The most important difference is the handling of nulls. Your query might seem to work the same with both in and exists, but when your sub-query returns null you might get a shock.

You might find that the existence of nulls causes exists to fail.

See Joe Celko's 'SQL for smarties' for a better explanation of when to use each.

Answer (score 1):

Not in is testing for the present of an element in a set of elements, so it is simpler.

Not exists can handle more complicated queries, including grouping (eg having sum(x)=z or having count(*)>3), results with multiple conditions (eg matching multiple elements), and can take advantage of indexes.

In some situations not in is easier to do than not exists.  I generally find this is where I am testing for the value of a key field in set of values.

As a rule of the thumb, I prefer not exists as it covers a lot more situations than not in.  Not exists can be used for every situation that not in is used for, but not the reverse.